# Angular 2 - Load the dynamic components one by one

Tags: angular, asynchronous, lazy-loading, ngfor

```
<div *ngFor="let header of headers">    
    <widget [header]="header" (loaded)="onLoaded($event)"></widget>
</div>
```

How to bind headers one by one based on the 'onLoaded' emit. Basically, I want the widget to load one by one after each successful data load(output method onLoaded emits boolean).

Answer (score 0):

Its very weird requirement so you can start like this

1) create empty new array forLoop: any[] = [];

2) Before displaying headers values( may be in ngonint()) add first element from the headers array to forLoop array

```
   `forLoop.push(headers.Shift())`  // it will remove first element from the headers array and add into forLoop
```

3)  now display forLoop array

```
<div *ngFor="let header of forLoop;trackBy: trackByFn">    
    <widget [header]="header" (loaded)="onLoaded($event)"></widget>
</div>

 trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
  }
```

4) on the onLoaded method remove second element from header array add into forloop array

```
onLoaded (){

  if(headers.length >0){
   forLoop.push(headers.Shift())
  }
}
```

5) continue this process for till the headers array is empty